# Why Flutter IconButton Animation Shows Under the Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In my app, I setup a IconButton to render over a Row with a color background. Unfortunately, the ripple animation on button press renders under the Row (as shown in the screencast). How do i make the ripple show over the Row?

```
class Card extends StatelessWidget {
final Issue issue;
Color _bgColor;

Card({this.issue}) {
  _bgColor = colorSwatch[issue.hashCode % colorSwatch.length];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 18, right: 18),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: _bgColor,
      border: new Border.all(color: _bgColor),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10.0) 
          ),
    ),
    child: Row(children: [
      IconButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
        icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white, size: 48),
        tooltip: 'Start ${issue.issueName}',
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
              child: Text(
                issue.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                softWrap: true,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              issue.issueName,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]));
  }
}
```

[image: screencast]

Comment: Wow! 3 year ago and the bug persists!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ripple is part of the `Material` effect. Wrap your `IconButton` with `Material`:

```
Material(
  color: _bgColor,
  child: IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
    icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white, size: 48),
    tooltip: 'Start ${issue.issueName}',
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

---

**UPDATE**

To be more specific to your goal, you can replace your `Container` with `Material`.

```
return Material(
  color: _bgColor,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
  child: Container(
     margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 18, right: 18),
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
     backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
     child: Row(
     ...
  ),
);
```

Comment: this works but Material does not have margin or padding. Ah let me just try that

Comment: so what i did is wrap the topmost Container with Material and it works. Update your answer to something that compiles and i'll accept as the answer :-)

Comment: sorry friend...looks like this solution was incomplete. It also needs  a Container with `backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply` as per @alexendar kwint (and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31541)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in the Flutter Framework.
This occurs only with IconButton, no problem with FlatButton.

Possible workaround is to set BlendMode to multiply **BlendMode.multiply**.
try this:

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.greenAccent[400],
              backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), onPressed: () {}),
            title: Text("issue title"),
            subtitle: Text("description"),
          ),
        ),
```

**Update**
issue on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31541)

Comment: glad to hear it's a bug but the above doesn't work for me. Note in my code i have a Row and not a ListTile...I applied blendmode to topmost container

Comment: ah looks like it needed a Material ancestor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Row` inside a `InkWell`, this will give you the touch ripples.

I have removed the background color of the container, had issues with it showing the ripple, as well as changed the text color to black.

[image]

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 18, right: 18),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          border: new Border.all(color: Colors.orange),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          // added here
          onTap: () {},
          child: Row(children: [
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
              icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.black, size: 48),
              tooltip: 'Start issue',
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      'issue.title',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      softWrap: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'issue.issueName',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }
```

References

[Add ripples](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples)

Answer (score 0):

Ripple always takes on top of  the material widgets. So if there is anything on top of the material widget you will see ripples under your widget.

Just wrap your IconButton with a Material widget  with the material set to use the "transparency" type and it should work.

You can use the below generic widget for adding ripples to your widgets.

```
class AddRipple extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function onTap;

  AddRipple({@required this.child, @required this.onTap});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Stack(
     children: <Widget>[
     child,
      Positioned.fill(
        child: new Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new InkWell(
              onTap: onTap,
            ))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can also take in a color in the constructor and user 'splashColor' property of the InkWell widget to set the splash color.